# Searching all files that begin with 's' and end with '.conf' with grep

Tags: linux, grep

Using the grep command search for the string `ip` in all files beginning with an `s` (case sensitive) and ending with `.conf` in the `/etc` directory.  Redirect the output to `/usr/local/thirdrock/grep1.txt`.

You should get 8 lines of output.

This is the question I've been given for my practical exam review, so far i have

```
grep "ip" s*.conf /etc
```

but I am returned `"no such file or directory"`.

My question is how do I search in all files beginning with an `s` and ending with `.conf` in the `/etc` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep "ip" s*.conf /etc` is searching for the string "ip" in all files in the current directory matching s*.conf and the "file" /etc, which is a directory.

`grep "ip" /etc/s*.conf` should do what you want.

You can redirect the standard output using `>`, but that wasn't part of your question, so I won't spoil it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep ip /etc/s*.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you

`cd /etc && grep -r --include='s*.conf' ip`